# Permissions to Search on SQL - MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

How to provide permissions to Search account on SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you are actually asking *what* the permissions should be, not *how* to allocate the permissions in SQL Server, the account used for search should have the **dbcreator** and the **securityadmin** server roles in the SSP Search database.

Refer Technet for more details:

[Plan for administrative and service accounts (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx)

In case you do need guidance on setting SQL permissions, refer here:

[Security Considerations for Databases and Database Applications (SQL Server 2005)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187648%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

[Security and Protection (SQL Server 2008)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510589.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry for being ignorant, but I need to know "how to allocate the permissions"? thanks

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your server. Expand "Security" and click on "Server Roles".  Double click dbcreator and add your Search account, then do the same to add the Search account to the securityadmin server role.